# Contact a specific fan of my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a Facebook competition set up and I need to contact a fan individually to let them know that they have won.

I thought when I was using Facebook as my page I would be able to write on a fan's wall - but I can't. I cannot send a direct message either?

I can do it from my personal account but I would like to keep my personal page separate from the fan page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a competition through your page, you will have the post regarding the competition on your page. The easiest way would be to post a "Congratulations" message with the profile picture of the winner. Many pages run contests through their page. Real fans who have 'Like'd your page will see it in their wall.